# stack level too deep error in jquery datatable with include modules outside class

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

when i first visit the page with jquery datatable it works fine but after visiting the page any page i go or reload  i get stack level too deep. I followed http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables

This is my code

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
class BookingsDatatable

  delegate :params, :link_to, to: :@view

  def initialize(view)
    @view = view
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      sEcho: params[:sEcho].to_i,
      iTotalRecords: Booking.count,
      iTotalDisplayRecords: bookings.total_entries,
      aaData: data
    }
  end

private

  def data
    bookings.map do |booking|
      [
        booking.booked_by,
        booking.client_ref,
        booking.booking_type,
        booking.start_date,
        booking.end_date,
       link_to("Invoices", booking_invoices_path(booking)),
       link_to( "Edit", edit_booking_path(booking))
      ]
    end
  end

  def bookings
    @bookings ||= fetch_bookings
  end

  def fetch_bookings
    bookings = Booking.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
    bookings = bookings.page(page).per_page(per_page)
    if params[:sSearch].present?
      bookings = bookings.where("client_ref like :search or booked_by like :search", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
    end
    bookings
  end

  def page
    params[:iDisplayStart].to_i/per_page + 1
  end

  def per_page
    params[:iDisplayLength].to_i > 0 ? params[:iDisplayLength].to_i : 10
  end

  def sort_column
    columns = %w[booked_by client_ref start_date end_date booking_type]
    columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i]
  end

  def sort_direction
    params[:sSortDir_0] == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  end
end
```

It works fine when i include the module Rails.application.routes.url_helpers inside the class but if it is at outside the class i get this error stack level too deep (works fine with  first page visit but error after that). i have no idea why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Stack level too deep means you have a circular dependency issue 99% of the times. I guess when you include the url helpers, it automatically loads all the classes to be able to generate the helpers, if there's an include inside one of this classes, it enters an infinite recursion. The problem has been documented earlier but was archived without a patch:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3144

Comment: this problem arises only if i included the module outside class definition but not inside